# How to answer "what area do you specialize in" when you're new?

Tags: job-search, position, terminology

This is a follow up to [Is it necessary to focus immediately when entering tech industry, and if so how?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/89258/is-it-necessary-to-focus-immediately-when-entering-tech-industry-and-if-so-how/89275#89275) I've just graduated and a lot of people ask me what area I'm into. I do not know the answer to this question. Right now I'm into IT and development but often times they want me to be more specific. I just went to a couple networking events and everyone said "back end or front end" when I said I'm into development. In school we had to do everything for yourself, so that is back end and front end. I had a co-op where I wrote a program for scientists and it parsed an XML input file, so would this be front end? Is there a clear distinction between back end and front end?

Also some people  think developers are in the IT department; I always thought they were separate? I know different people use words differently and different companies have different structures, but in networking events and interviews it wasn't a good response "what do you consider a front end developer?" when they asked which area of development I'm into.

Comment: Do you have any personal interests? Web development, artificial intelligence, security, something?

Comment: Difference between frontend and backend is frontend is what the user sees and interacts with whilst the backend is often the database and application. This is usually the part that does all the work. As an example of technologies, frontend could be HMTL and CSS whilst backend could be PHP, Python etc. There might be a better way to explain that but I hope that helps a little. Often a developer can do both in small organisations as I did in my last job and to be honest I much prefer backend than frontend.

Comment: @Bugs is pretty much correct. Note however that many (especially non-tech) get it wrong and think that "server" is backend and "client" is frontend. An AngularJS app running in the client's browser is very much a backend thing.

Comment: "I wrote a program for scientists and it parsed an XML input file, so would this be front end?" - a front-end for this might be a GUI or web page that lets the scientists carry out the parsing process. Depending on the scientists who use it, a simple command line client might also work (technically a front-end too, albeit a simple one).

Comment: See [Is the term 'Front-End' synonymous with 'Client-Side'? If so, is this always the case?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/188521/is-the-term-front-end-synonymous-with-client-side-if-so-is-this-always-the)

Comment: I don't really see a practically answerable question here: your interests are your own. If your studies didn't teach you the difference between front end and back end development or the term full stack then you may need to do some self-studying. But that's not a workplace question either.

Comment: “What area do you specialize in when you're new?” Learning

Comment: Parsing an XML file is back-end (kinda towards middle-end) - designing the output display is front-end...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not answer specifically to this question, but talk about your interests. As you said, you are new, so the only thing the recruiter needs to know is **what do you want to do from now on.** For example, you can say:

> 1. I would like to start a career into a front-end position.
> 2. I would like to gain experience into IT field.
> 3. I feel very interested about a developer position, as I have little experience gained from school projects and I enjoyed them.
>
> etc...

The recruiter needs to understand what motivates you, in order to make a match between you and an available position in his company.

Source: I have been a recruiter for a contractor firm, with activities in various fields (aerospace, railways, automotive, defence, health and so on). So we used to have a lot of open positions, including for begineers. In such cases, what I looked for was highly motivated candidates with high learning and adaptation skills, more than candidates with a "specialization".

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question in the title - you can just be honest and say that you don't really *have* a specialty yet, if your talking about a specific role you're interested in then recount some positive experiences or skills you have that relate to that role.

Not having a specialty isn't really a bad thing, nor is it unexpected given that you are just starting out, after all most CS education courses are quite broad by design. So this shouldn't be a massive impediment to getting entry-level roles. Yes some prospective employers will be looking for someone who is stronger in certain areas that match their business need but others will be looking for someone they can shape into a role and there may even be those who actively prefer a "jack of all trades" candidate! This is especially true of small companies as they can't afford to have a specialist in each area - my first tech job after graduation after graduation had me doing web development (front and back end), Windows applications, Windows services, server administration/infrastructure, and first line tech support!

Fast forward 7 years and I have specialized somewhat since then but I still have a fairly diverse skill set to the point where I usually have 3-4 versions of my CV which are tailored to different types of role in order to highlight the skills and experience that they are looking for.

At the risk of straying into career-advice here I would say that having read both this question and your earlier one it seems that you are utterly overwhelmed with the possible options you have and you're tying yourself into knots over it. I'd point out that choosing what you do straight after graduation is not about finding your forever job so try not to overthink it. I've known many people who had very definite career plans for after school or university and very few of them are now doing what they thought they would be and even fewer of them went straight into their "planned" career. So cast a wide net for any jobs you think you can do (if they look interesting to you then that's a bonus) and start applying, once you've got a couple of years of real world experience you'll probably have a much better idea of the sorts of roles you want to be doing.